# Salesforce: How can I use the Contract amendment API to update quantity and list price

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

I require assistance in understanding how I can manipulate the Contract Amender to update values in  the amended quotes produced.

I'm using the API [Contract Amender](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_contract_amender.htm).

After I ran the code:

`String contractID = '000....';`

`String quoteJSON = SBQQ.ServiceRouter.load('SBQQ.ContractManipulationAPI.ContractAmender', contractID, null);`

It created the amended opportunity and quote. However, I want to be able to update the list price, discount, and quantity for the items.  Is there a possibility to do this.

The code will be running inside a batch job.

I know there is the context approach but I do not understand how to define what context is and/or how to use it.

Is there a way for the amended quote that it produces can have its price, quantity, discount updated?